# PDF print using powerbuilder 10.5/Ghostscript

Tags: ghostscript, powerbuilder

Can anyone pls tell me how to use ghostscript to print files using powerbuilder 10.5

what files I need to add. what version of ghostscript I need to use. different version for vista/xp/win 7.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that what you're looking for is printing via datawindow’s SaveAs command to PDF...

```
ll_rc = dw_report.saveas(ls_filename, PDF!, false)
```

...you'll need Ghostscript installed (available) in two locations:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\gs
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\Shared\PowerBuilder\gs

The second folder is for the PowerBuilder IDE.

I’m using Ghostscript version 8.7.1. It works fine with PowerBuilder 11/12/12.5 in both Win XP and Win 7 environments. 
Not sure about PB10.5 and more recent GS versions. The older Ghostscripts can be found here:

http://downloads.ghostscript.com/public/

Hope this helps.